# Javascript arrays or object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wish to grab content from various sources, using different API calls, and collate them all into an object or array with the same format. I am getting stuck with javascript arrays and objects, and none of the examples I find seem to do what I want to do. This is the format I want to store. This is pseudo coded for an example of what I want to achieve

```
var content = new Object();
getTweets();
getSoundCloud();
display();


function getTweets() {

    //first result
    content.type = "tweet
    content.text = "the text of the tweet"
    content.image = "the image from the tweet"

    return content;
}

function getSoundCloud() {
    //second result
    content.type = "soundcloud
    content.text = "the name of the song"
    content.image = "the image of the song"

    return content;
}


function display() {
    //for each content
    {
        $("#container").append(content.text);
    }

}
```

The first result is generated by one function call, and the Second result is generated by a different function call.

I want these functions to add all of the content together into the same format object. Once the object is populated, I wish to iterate it in a different function and display on the screen.

How do I make this object? I have tried it but the data is always the same, ie, overwritten with the same values. In php this would be an associative array perhaps or something like

I want to have an object for each piece of content I have, and can loop through it

```
content[0].type = "tweet"
content[1].type = "coundcloud"
```

Any suggestions with examples would be great.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you have *many of something* you should immediately think

> I need to store these things in an array.

When your "things" are *complex* and have various properties/ state, you should immediately think:

> I need to create an object to store them.

... so what would be best here is an array of objects. Each function will create objects and add them to `content`, which we'll switch to an array:

```
var content = []; // Array
getTweets();
getSoundCloud();
display();


function getTweets() {
    var tweet = {}; // This is an object

    tweet.type = "tweet";
    tweet.text = "The text of the tweet";
    tweet.image = "The image of the tweet";

    content.push(tweet); // add the object to the array.
}

function getSoundCloud() {
    var soundcloudThing = {};

    soundcloudThing.type = "soundcloud"
    soundcloudThing.text = "the name of the song"
    soundcloudThing.image = "the image of the song"

    content.push(soundcloudThing);
}
```

Now when it comes to *showing* this content, as have an array; the obvious thing to do here is *iterate* over it;

```
function display() {
    for (var i=0;i<content.length;i++)
    {
        $("#container").append(content[i].text);

        // You can also use content[i].image and content[i].type in here
    }
}
```

Note that `[]` and `{}` is [literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Literals) for creating arrays and objects. It's use is favoured over `new Array()` and `new Object()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pdXsA/2/

```
var content = [];
content.push(getTweets());
content.push(getSoundCloud());
display();

function getTweets() {
    return{
        type : "tweet",
        text : "the text of the tweet",
        image : "the image from the tweet"                    
    };
}

function getSoundCloud() {
    return{
        type : "soundcloud",
        text : "the name of the song",
        image : "the image of the song"                    
    };
}

function display() {
    content.forEach(function(item){
        $("#container").append(item.text +"<br/>");
    });
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

`content` should be an array of objects, each function adds its object into the content array :

```
var content = []; // empty array
getTweets();
getSoundCloud();
display();


function getTweets() {
    content.push ({  //first result
      type: "tweet",
      text: "the text of the tweet",
      image: "the image from the tweet"
    });
}

function getSoundCloud() {
    content.push ({  //second result
      type: "soundcloud",
      text: "the name of the song",
      image: "the image of the song"
    });
}


function display() {
    content.forEach (v) {
       // code to format the object v appropriately
       var vtext = v.type + ' : ' + v.text;
        $("#container").append(vtext);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just sussed it out like this

```
var content = {
    text: this.text.linkify().linkuser().linktag(),
    image: this.profile_image_url,
    type: 'tweet'
};

arrayContent.push(content);
```

I can now loop through it, and each Content and display it!